# Popup appear on wrong position if i scroll page first before clicking on corresponding link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Live site- http://uposonghar.com/new-video/

Please hover embedded YouTube video then you will see 2 sharing button, one for Facebook & one for Twitter, click on that link a instant sharing JavaScript window will appear & another popup appears after 2 second.

My problem is with second popup. That is not appear on right place if i scroll page before clicking on sharing button(that is working perfectly if i click on sharing button without scrolling page).

Check this screenshot(i scroll page before clicking on sharing button)-
[image]

My code-

```
 #reveal-modal-bg {
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 z-index: 100;
 display: none;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.reveal-modal {
 visibility: hidden;
 top: 100px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -300px;
 width: 520px;
 background: #eee;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 101;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 text-align:center;
 padding:20px 15px 30px;
}
```

Comment: You may try position:absolute for this, it might help

Comment: I want to keep scroll so need to scroll active while popup(popup will appear on center on the screen but page scroll). Any way to do that with absolute position. Maybe with JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: Try jQuery bpopup plugin, it works like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit 1

Remove `top` inline CSS property from `#myModal` div and keep `.reveal-model` position `fixed`

```
 .reveal-modal {
 position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I want to keep scroll so need to scroll active while popup(popup will appear on center on the screen but page scroll). Any way to do that with absolute position. Maybe with JavaScript/jQuery